# How to assign int* -or- float* to void* and use the result later?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting, void

im pretty new in c++ and my problem is the following:

i need an array in which i want so save values. all valus are of the same type.
there are two cases: the array should save int values or float.
when i compile, i dont knwo yet which type it will be, so it has to be defined while executing the programm.

i tried something like this:

```
void* myArray;
int a = 10;
if(something){
    myArray = new int[a];
}
else{
    myArray = new float[a];
}
```

after this i want so calculate things with these values, but i always get errors because the array is still void

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast`, but I have a feeling you should be using templates rather than continue down whatever path you're going now.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to approach this - from the information you provided, the best one is probably std::array and a templated funciton...  but I have a feeling there's a better way to solve whatever problem you have.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: `void *` is very rarely the answer to any problem in modern C++.

Comment: use templates for this.

Comment: `variant<vector<int>, vector<float>>`

Comment: "the array is still void" is missing the problem - `myArray` *isn't* an array.

Comment: This looks strongly like an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).  Instead of asking how to make your `void` array work, you should ask about how to manage data of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this in C++:

- You could use a `void*` and add `reinterpret_cast<...>` as needed,
- You could make an array of `union`s that have both an `int` and a `float`, or
- You could use templates.

The first two approaches are idiomatic to C, but not to C++. Both approaches are workable, but they result in solutions that are hard to understand and maintain.

The third approach lets you do things very cleanly:

```
template <typename T>
void calc() {
    // You could use std::vector<T> here for even better flexibility
    T* a = new T[10];
    ... // Perform your computations here
    delete[] a;
    // You don't need a delete if you use std::vector<T>
}

int main() {
    ...
    // You can make a type decision at runtime
    if (mustUseInt) {
        calc<int>();
    } else {
        calc<float>();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct calculator : public boost::static_visitor<> {
  void operator()(const std::vector<int>& vi) const {
    // evaluate the array as ints
  }

  void operator()(const std::vector<float>& vf) const {
    // evaluate the array as floats
  }

};

using nasty_array = boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>;
std::unique_ptr<nasty_array> myArray;
int a = 10;
if (something) {
  myArray.reset(std::vector<int>(a));
}
else {
  myArray.reset(std::vector<float>(a));
}

boost::apply_visitor( calculator(), *myArray );
```